# Clone with SSH Issues

Tags: ssh, git-clone

I am trying to clone a repository on git.dscoe.org

This is the situation: 
-Created key using keygen in terminal
-Added key to Gitlab

Getting this error: 
git@git.dscoe.org: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

I've tried changing the ownership of the .ssh file, and the result from ls -al is attached in the image. [image]

This is how I have my config file [image]

Debugging output [image][image]

Any help would be so amazing! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Try running `ssh -vvT git@git.dscoe.org`. The "-vv" will cause ssh to print debugging information. Then [edit] your question to include the debug output.

Comment: Just did that! Thank you so much!

Comment: In the future, it's preferred to include the debugging output as text rather than an image. Format the debugging output as a code block.

Comment: Anyway, the debug trace shows that your ssh client offered the "keys_to_kingdom" key to the server, and the server didn't accept it. The key may not be set up correctly on the server, or your local copy of the key (or the keys_to_kingdom.pub file) may be wrong somehow. I also note that you're connecting to the default ssh port on the server; check to see if you're supposed to be connecting to a different port for gitlab.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added:

- the public key content (as *one* line) the the GitLab hosted on `git.dscoe.org` (and not to your `gitlab.com` account)
- set the [right permissions to `~/.ssh`, keys and `config`](https://superuser.com/a/215506/141)
- add the key to ssh-agent if it is protected by a passphrase
- or try and generate a new one with:

  ```
  ssh-keygen -t rsa -m PEM -P ""
  ```